# Retrive IP address from WMI query using PHP

Tags: php, windows, wmi

I'm trying to get a script going that retrieves NIC card info of a remote host on my network.

Here's my query:

```
$wmi_networkadapter = $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionID LIKE 'Local Area Connection'");
```

Here's the Output:

```
   foreach ($wmi_networkadapter as $wmi_call) {
        //Caption
        $Caption = $wmi_call->Caption;
        echo "<b>Caption:</b> $Caption<br>";

        //MACAddress
        $MACAddress = $wmi_call->MACAddress;
        echo "<b>MACAddress:</b> $MACAddress df<br>";                                       
    }
```

I can get the Macaddress, and Caption (Name of NIC), but I can't figure out how to get the IP address. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I was able to get the IP Address doing this.

Using this query:

```
$wmi_networkadapter = $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPENabled = 'True'");
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($wmi_networkadapter as $wmi_call) {
    //Caption
    $Caption = $wmi_call->Caption;
    echo "<b>Caption:</b> $Caption<br>";

    //MACAddress
    $MACAddress = $wmi_call->MACAddress;
    echo "<b>MACAddress:</b> $MACAddress<br>";      

    //IP ADDRESS
    $ip = $wmi_call->IPAddress;
    foreach ($ip as $key => $value) {
     echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience specifically working with WMI, but what results do you get when calling `var_dump($wmi_call)`?

Comment: object(variant)#10 (0) { }

Comment: How about var_dump($wmi_call->NetworkAddresses)? This link may be helpful too, specifically the "..determine which IP address has been assigned to a given network connection?" section. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx